# Can't call ViewController method from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

In AppDelagate I call the following in a method

```
func example() {
    ViewController().test()
}
```

and In my ViewController the method is

```
func test() {
    testView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    buttonTapped(UIButton())
    restartTimer()
}
```

but it crashes whenever I call the method, due to a nil error with testView. testView is a view in ViewController and not in AppDelegate, but I don't know how to make it so the method executes like how it would if i called it in the ViewController.

Comment: creating an instance of ViewController in the manner that you did does not create it from the storyboard. I am assuming your testView is an IBOutlet?

Comment: testView is an IBOutlet

Comment: have you imported ViewController in appDelegate?

Comment: I tried but for some reason it didn't work

Comment: Name your ViewController something else as ViewController is the default Class Name for ViewController

Comment: Have you defined UI for your ViewController in storyboard or in xib?

Answer (score 1):

An `IBOutlet` is `nil` until the view controller calls `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` did not occur since you tried to instantiate the class directly via the call `ViewController()`.

Thus, `testView` is nil, as expected. Your `AppDelegate` should not be responsible for the `ViewController` logic anyhow.

Comment: It still crashes after it completes the viewDidLoad method

Comment: It doesn't complete the `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know by now, your crash is happening due the fact you're accessing a `IBOutlet` before it get the chance to be initialized. So I'm guessing the `testView` is declared sort of like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!
```

**Solution A**

You can turn it optional instead to avoid this crash:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView?
```

And change the syntax in your VC to:

```
testView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

**Solution B**

If you really need to turn the User Interaction off at this point, you can force the view to load:

```
let myVc = ViewController()
_ = myVc.view // this will force the myVc.view to be loaded
myVc.test()
```

This way your `IBOutlet`s will have the chance to initialize before you run the `test()` method.